# How to properly align the scroll bar of a div

Tags: css, styles, scrollbar

I had this question while i was working with a new glassmorphism project
this is the problem
[Click this link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYyIW.png)
and i have no idea what to do...
so can anyone find an answer?

Comment: Im sorry to inform you we might be unable to help without any code. Please refer to the Minimal Reproducible Example guide of this site to find out how to ask your questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.